# MSBUILD exclude cs files

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild

I have a class library (TestClassLib) with following classes/interfaces.

IA.cs

A.cs (Implements IA)

IB.cs

B.cs (Implements IB)

A and B have no dependency.

In the TestClasslib.csproj, i have the following XML

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Builtdir>built</Builtdir>
    <AssemblyName>Dabba</AssemblyName>
    <OutputPath>Bin\</OutputPath>
    <Configurations>Debug;Release;Test</Configurations>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>


  <ItemGroup>
    <CSFile Include="*.cs;" Exclude="B.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="Compile">
    <Csc Sources="@(CSFile)" OutputAssembly="$(AssemblyName).dll" TargetType="dll" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Just want to exclude B.cs when the dll is created. 
Is it possible to exclude few classes which has no dependency on other classes ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to exclude some class in build process,
add the annotations below in `.csproj`. Then the generated `dll` is not related to `B.cs`.

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <Compile Remove="B.cs" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Thanks.. It is working.. <CSFile Include="*.cs;" Exclude="B.cs" /> why is this not working ?

Comment: I think <CSFile ... Exclude="..." /> is to exclude when packaging, but <Compile Remove...> is to exclude files when compling. It's totally different.